# reledpar: problem with \startlock...\endlock command

Tags: double-sided, line-numbering, reledpar

anyone can help me understand why in reledpar package, when using \startlock ...\endlock  one of the block lines seems numbered

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{changepage}


\firstlinenum*{5}
\linenumincrement*{5}

\begin{document}
    \newpage
    
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart\centering
                 \startlock ATTO I\\SCENA PRIMA\\
                 \textit{Agnese seduta sul gradino della sua porta  a dritta,  che finisce di allacciarsi il  busto. Sbuffa per il caldo e spesso si  gratta. Mastro  Berardo da dentro ed  Angioletta e più indietro  Andreuccio  poggiato ad una quinta.}\endlock
                \pend
                \pstart 
                AGNESE. Nu canchere, quanta pugge se trove. Dice bone Marie delu stuorte ca sse trove chelle dele vennegne; e puo sta chesa mie strette, azzuffechete – aghè lu vere ca n’ce manche cose – ma che buo'? Pe' lu calde e pe' lu pugge n’ce se pò rsiste.
```

[image]

As you can see line 5 should be 4. the next one should be five.
Thanks!